# Erratic behavior of Matlab's legend function

Tags: matlab, legend

I was working on a MATLAB project and found some strange behavior of the `legend`  function. Here is the code to reproduce the issue:

```
X=rand(3,100);
a=rand(3,100);
b=rand(3,100);
figure(1); hold on;
plot(0.17663,'m');
plot(1.223,'y');
plot(X,a,'r');
plot(X,b,'g');
legend({'s1','s2','a','b'});
```

My question is: The legend in the picture shows the same color for plot 3 and plot 4. Instead it should show red and green respectively. Is there something wrong with `legend`?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6JbH.png]

Comment: possible duplicate of [legend for group of lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141403/legend-for-group-of-lines)

Comment: Not a duplicate per se, because in the linked question this is the wanted behavior why here it is a simple mistake, but the same cause, therefore it should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

The commands `plot(X,a,'r')` and `plot(X,b,'g')` are not what you might expect. As `X` is a `3-by-100` array they will plot 100 lines, each consisting of 3 points, start, middle, end. The legend entries will correspond to each single line, so you should expect 100 red legend entries. You will see different behavior if you pass transposed arrays: `plot(X.',a.','r')`. This will plot 3 lines, each consisting of 100 points.