# Add legend to a group of lines

Tags: matlab, plot

I have to plot a group of lines (10 in total, divided in 2 groups of 5 each), but I want the legend only for the groups.

It seems easy, I followed the accepted answer here: [legend for group of lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141403/legend-for-group-of-lines)

and it makes sense to me, but when I execute it, I get an error:

> Operands to the || and && operators
>    must be convertible to logical scalar values.
>             Error in legend (line 198)
>              elseif narg > 0 &&
>              ~ischar(varargin{1}) && ...

this is the code, I don't know if it's because of the "eval" command but I get the plot...

```
figure(3)
h1=plot(res(:,17),(res(:,16)./10^6),prop,...
res(:,64),(res(:,92)./10^6),prop,...
res(:,65),(res(:,93)./10^6),prop,...
res(:,66),(res(:,94)./10^6),prop,...
res(:,67),(res(:,95)./10^6),prop,...
'linewidth',2);
hold on
for ii=1:ngrains
      eval(['h2(',num2str(ii),',1)=plot(',names{ii},'.VMSTRAIN,',names{ii},'.VMSTRESS,prop2,''linewidth'',2)']);
hold on
```

[image: plot]

Here is the code I used to add the legend:

```
   legend([h1 h2],{'label1', 'label2'});
```

Comment: Ugh, do not use `eval` like this. Store your data in a [structure](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html) and utilize [dynamic field references](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/). Or use a [map container](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way of declaring a group of `LineSeries` via the `plot` function. What you can do is to "fake" the grouping, by concatenating the values and inserting `NaN`s between them for the purpose of breaking the lines:

```
%// Build some data
t  = transpose(0:0.001:pi);
x1 = sin(t);
x2 = sin(t + pi/6);
y1 = cos(t);
y2 = cos(t + pi/6);

%// Aggregate data for plotting
TX = [ t; NaN;  t];
 X = [x1; NaN; x2];
TY = [ t; NaN;  t];
 Y = [y1; NaN; y2];

%// Do the plotting
plot(   TX, X, '--b',  TY, Y, '-r');
legend('dotted blue',   'full red');
```

Please note that you cannot handle separately the visibility (or other property values) of the `LineSeries`, because there are no actual separated `LineSeries` within a "group".

**Later Edit**

If you want to use the trick of annotating only the first `LineSeries` from the group that share the same styles, maybe you should write:

```
 legend([h1(1), h2(1)], 'string1', 'string2');
```

Comment: Didn't see your post when I made mine. I feel that it is better to make legend entries for selected line series than to mess with the data. Nevertheless, nice NaN trick.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I agree that annotating only some representative `LineSeries` is more clean and flexible. The only problem (which I personally face while exchanging data trough `.fig` files -- believe me it happens :-D) is reconstructing the groups from the `LineSeries` properties like `Color`, `LineStyle`, `LineWidth` etc. In contrast it is quite easy to get the data for the entire group, and split it around the `NaN`s.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `plot` is a vector that contains one entry for every line series plotted. In your case `h1` is `5 x 1`, and `h2` is `ngrains x 1`. You should do `legend([h1(1) h2(1)], {'label1', 'label2'});`. This will assign a legend entry only to the first line series of each group.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that your `h2` column vector and you are trying to concatenate with `h1` as  if it were a row vector.

try `legend([h1;h2], ...` or `legend([h1, h2'],...`