# Changing the legend of a figure so that various lines share the same legend entry

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

A colleague has passed me a `.fig` file that has many lines on the same plots and they are coloured based on which group they belong to. The figure is shown below for reference.

I need to change the legend so that lines with the same colour have the same legend entry. The problem is that I don't have access to the raw data so I can't use the method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141403/legend-for-group-of-lines) so is there a way to change the legend entries just using the `.fig` file? I tried changing some of the legend names to `NaN` in the property inspector but that just changes the entries to NaN.

[image: What I have so far]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the `*.fig` file you can extract any included data with the 'get' method if you have understood the MATLAB [Graphics Objects Hierarchy](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/graphics-objects.html).

For example, see the left plot below as example of your `*.fig` file. you can extract the data in there by digging through the `Children` of your current figure object.

```
% Open your figure
fig = openfig('your_figure.fig');
% fig = gcf     % If you have the figure already opened
title('loaded figure')

% Get all objects from figure (i.e. legend and axis handle)
Objs = get(fig, 'Children');      
% axis handle is second entry of figure children
HA = Objs(2);          
% get line objects from axis (is fetched in reverse order)
HL = flipud(get(HA, 'Children'));     

% retrieve data from line objects
for i = 1:length(HL)
    xData(i,:) = get(HL(i), 'XData');
    yData(i,:) = get(HL(i), 'YData');
    cData{i} = get(HL(i), 'Color');
end
```

xy data of all lines in the figure is now extracted to `xData` and `yData`. The color information is saved to cell `cData`. You can now replot the figure with a legend the way you want (e.g. using the SO solution you found already):

```
% Draw new figure with data extracted from old figure
figure()
title('figure with reworked legend')
hold on
for i = 1:length(HL)
    h(i) = plot(xData(i,:), yData(i,:), 'Color', cData{i});
end

% Use method of the SO answer you found already to combine equally colored
% line objects to the same color
legend([h(1), h(3)], 'y1', 'y2+3')
```

Result is the plot below on the right, where each color is only listed once.

[image]